# How to set a custom size to FAB in Ionic v4?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm creating a floating action button using Ionic 4, and I want to make it bigger.
If I give the button a class and go to the scss file to change the height and width, the position is messing up (I use center both horizontally and vertically), it changes the size but makes the button START at the center of the screen and drop down from there and not actually centered (hope it made sense right there)

How do I do this correctly? All of the answers on the web are irrelevant to v4 unfortunately

here is my code for the html:

```html
  <ion-fab vertical="center" horizontal="center" slot="fixed">
    <ion-fab-button color="primary" [routerLink]="['/timer']" class="start-btn"><p>Start</p>
    </ion-fab-button>
  </ion-fab>
```

And the code for the css file:

```css
  .start-btn {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
```

I need the size to change AND the position to stay as expected

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Angular style binding to **change Ion Fab size even dynamically:**

```
<ion-col> <!--parent-->
 <ion-fab #fab>
  <ion-fab-button
   [style.width]="getDiameterPx()"
   [style.height]="getDiameterPx()"
```

and then after resize operation, you have to recalculate and set the top-left position (using ratio coordinates x,y)

```
fab.nativeElement.style.left = (x -  this.fabRadius/widthOfParent) * 100 + '%';
fab.nativeElement.style.top = (y - this.fabRadius/heightOfParent) * 100 + '%';
```

(obtain element by using `@ViewChild('fab', { read: ElementRef, static: false }) fab: ElementRef;`)

The parent should have `style="position: relative;"`.

Diameter function:

```
getDiameterPx() {
    return this.fabRadius * 2 + 'px'; // radius*2 = diameter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's work for me：

```
<ion-fab vertical="bottom" style="align-self: center;" slot="fixed">
  <ion-fab-button>
    <i class="iconfont ion-timer" style="margin-right: 5px;"></i>test
  </ion-fab-button>
</ion-fab>
```